# Reference same SQL column to use in CASE clause

Tags: sql, db2, switch-statement, case-when

I need tome assistance with an SQL query in DB2 using QMF for Qrkstation z/OS
V11.1 Fix Pack 3.

I am querying a couple of fields from different tables. I am showing some timestamps too. I need a CASE clause which uses one of those timestamps.

The idea is that one of the timestamps can have data or not (null) because I am using LEFT JOIN with that table (if value then bring it if not then blank) So the CASE clause would need to check that column/field and if it has data (IS NOT NULL) then put value 'Delivered'. This logic is no working for me as seen in the following images.

```
select distinct
    z.po_id, 
    max(CASE 
           WHEN dcus.ship_evnt_tms IS NOT NULL THEN 'Delivered'
           WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(Z.CAD_TMS) <= 0 THEN 'On time CAD'
           WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(Z.CAD_TMS) between 1 and 2 THEN 'Less than 3 days after CAD'
           WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(Z.CAD_TMS) between 3 and 5 THEN 'Between 3 & 5 days after CAD'
           WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(Z.CAD_TMS) between 6 and 10 THEN 'Between 6 & 10 days after CAD'
           WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(Z.CAD_TMS) >= 10 THEN 'More than 10 days after CAD'
           ELSE 'Non physical' 
       END) AS Aging,
    max(z.cad_tms) as cad_tms, 
    max(dcus.ship_evnt_tms) as DELV_DATE_CUS
from
    SCHEMA.TABLE z
left join 
    SCHEMA.TABLE1 A ON z.po_id = a.po_id
left join
    SCHEMA.TABLE2 scus ON (A.SHIP_ID = scus.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scus.loc_type = 'CUS')
left join 
    SCHEMA.TABLE3 dcus ON (scus.SHIP_ID = dcus.SHIP_ID_856 AND scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcus.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')
left join
    SCHEMA.TABLE2 scdc ON (A.SHIP_ID = scdc.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scdc.loc_type = 'CDC')
left join 
    SCHEMA.TABLE3 dcdc ON (scdc.SHIP_ID = dcdc.SHIP_ID_856 AND scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcdc.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')
```

[image]

As seen on the image, the first couple of rows which have data tms on the last column, should appear as Delivered based on CASE clause logic (at least as far as I am aware of) What is more, the last records show correct calculations and results, based on the other WHEN statements.

I've tried removing the table alias (dcus) in order to "reference" to the column value itself, but it gives me a SQL error (Ambiguous reference)

[image]

If anyone knows a different approach or sees some kind of mistake in the clause, please let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: Update...function seems to work if I remove last statement in the CASE clause...The ones Delivered show up, but NULL on all that are more than 10 (is logic cause no statement) If I add the last ELSE for instance "dcus.ship_evnt_tms is null then 'More than 10 days...' It won't work...even putting the More than 10 days result directly in ELSE clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you are selecting the maximum value returned by the case statement for each id rather than the value of the CAS Statement for the maximum date. So the order of those values is (On time CAD, Non physical, More than 10 days..., Less than 3 days..., Delivered, Between 6..., Between 3). So if all those id's had a record where `ship_evnt_tms` was null, the max vbalue coming out of that case will be `More than 10 days...`. It is also strange that you are using distinct with aggregation.  Instead you could just group on `po_id`. Maybe try:

```
select
z.po_id, 
CASE 
  WHEN max(dcus.ship_evnt_tms) is not null then 'Delivered'
  WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(max(Z.CAD_TMS)) <= 0 then 'On time CAD'
  WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(max(Z.CAD_TMS)) between 1 and 2 then 'Less than 3 days after CAD'
  WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(max(Z.CAD_TMS)) between 3 and 5 then 'Between 3 & 5 days after CAD'
  WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(max(Z.CAD_TMS)) between 6 and 10 then 'Between 6 & 10 days after CAD'
  WHEN days(CURRENT_timestamp) - days(max(Z.CAD_TMS)) >= 10 then 'More than 10 days after CAD'
  ELSE 'Non physical' 
END AS Aging,

max(z.cad_tms) as cad_tms, 
max(dcus.ship_evnt_tms) as DELV_DATE_CUS

from SCHEMA.TABLE z

left join SCHEMA.TABLE1 A ON z.po_id = a.po_id

left JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 scus ON (A.SHIP_ID = scus.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scus.loc_type = 'CUS')

left join SCHEMA.TABLE3 dcus ON (scus.SHIP_ID = dcus.SHIP_ID_856 AND scus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcus.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcus.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')

left JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 scdc ON (A.SHIP_ID = scdc.SHIP_ID AND A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scdc.loc_type = 'CDC')

left join SCHEMA.TABLE3 dcdc ON (scdc.SHIP_ID = dcdc.SHIP_ID_856 AND scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = dcdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CD856 
AND dcdc.SHIP_EVNT_CD = 'D')

group by z.po_id
```

Comment: Great advice! I've updated the query and got to retrieve all the correct info. I am trying to enhance the query by adding another condition, that when scdc.ship_event_tms is not null and scdc.ship_to_ctry in ('XX','ZZ') then 'Delivered-BP'. I've tried to add it below the first condition, with max() on both fields, but I don't get the correct value in Aging. Is it possible to combine first clause adding that ctry condition? Thanks

Comment: No worries...I was using incorrect ship_evnt_tms...I needed to use scdc in case of scus...that brought correct values. I got my work solved. Thanks a lot!